# Private/Public variables Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am coding some scripts for a googlespreadsheet. One of the functions needs to obtain a userinput. Afterwards, I need to make use of the input in a few other functions, one sample I've shown below. Question is, do I need to call the function 'Setup()' each time I need to make use of the input? That will mean asking for the input multiple times, which I know is stupid.

How could I work around this?

Thanks!

```
var setupdone = false;

function Setup(){
  if(!setupdone){
    numofTeams = Browser.inputBox('Confirm the number of Teams');
    var ui = Browser.msgBox('Ensure that the teams are arranged according to lane allocations below', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    setupdone = true;
  }

  var semisraw = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Secondary Group 1');
  var range = semisraw.getDataRange();
  values = range.getValues();
};

function numofTeamsprint(){
  Setup();
  Browser.msgBox('Setup is Complete!');
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any variable, as one may call it, is called a `global variable` if the variable is attached to the `window` object.

Consider the example.

```
var thisIsAGlobalVar = 4;

function method1() {
    var thisIsALocalVar;

    // My Code
    // 1. thisIsALocalVar is available in this function only
    // 2. Its scope would be destroyed as soon as the function itself goes out of scope
    // 3. thisIsAGlobalVar can be access here.

    //Suppose I introduce another variable, without the var keyword, like the one below, inside of a function, the JavaScript interpretter adds it to the window object

    thisAlsoIsAGlobalVar = "Global";

}

function method2 () {

    //My Code
    // 1. thisIsAGlobalVar can be accessed here also

    //Other Code

    //Now that thisAlsoIsAGlobalVar is declared in method1, it has become global and hence can be used here as well
    //Only Pre-condition being method1 should be called firsr

    console.log(thisAlsoIsAGlobalVar); // Would print "Global"

    console.log(thisIsALocalVar); // Would be "undefined"

}
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could set `numofTeams` equal to `-1`, and then only ask for input if `numofTeams` is `< 0`, like this:

```
var numofTeams = -1;

function Setup(){
  if (numofTeams < 0) {
    numofTeams = Browser.inputBox('Confirm the number of Teams');
  }
  var ui = Browser.msgBox('Ensure that the teams are arranged according to lane allocations below', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  var semisraw = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Secondary Group 1');
  var range = semisraw.getDataRange();
  values = range.getValues();
};

function numofTeamsprint(){
  Setup();
  Logger.log(values[0][0]);
};
```

If you need that input again for some reason, just set it back to `-1`, and then run `Setup()`.

Comment: Cool, so, I will still be calling the function again for getting the value out. But because of the setupdone check, the user will not be prompted. Am I right in saying that?

Comment: Yep exactly.  You can call it as many times as you want, and as long as `numofTeams` is less than zero, the user won't be prompted.  The other answer uses the same concept, but with booleans. Which one you choose depends on your design.

Comment: ok I tried that and it doesn't seem to work. Each time I run Setup, it still prompts the user for input. Edited code is in the original qn

Comment: I might point out though that I used `-1` because in Javascript, both `0` and `false` will evaluate to `false` if you write you code like this: `if (numofTeams) { ... }`.  Since you might want `numofTeams` to be zero, the boolean may introduce a headache later down the line.

Comment: Well, each time you refresh your page, `numofTeams` will be reset, you realize. :)  If you want a solution that will last over multiple page refreshes, you'll have to store it somewhere more persistent, like GET or a cookie.

Comment: Right! Will try and figure a way to store it as a cookie.

Comment: @CodeNewbie - and you're on your way, good luck and stick with it, it gets easier after a few weeks.  If an answer helped solve your question, the community appreciates if you mark 'Accept'.  Upvotes on helpful answers are nice too :)

Answer (score 0):

If you define you variables as global (outside the functions), then you can test to see if they have been set and only prompt for them is they have not been set.

```
var setupDone = false;

function setup () {
  if (!setupDone) {
    // do whatever
    setupDone = true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Cool, so, I will still be calling the function again for getting the value out. But because of the setupdone check, the user will not be prompted. Am I right in saying that? Thank you!

Comment: ok I tried that and it doesn't seem to work. Each time I run Setup, it still prompts the user for input